# Pass values of an Observable to two distinct Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to pass values of an Observable to two distinct Observables.

For simplicity, suppose I have an Observable created from a dictionary that has two values: `obs = rxjs.Observable.of({a: 1, b: 2})`.
I first want to pass the first value `a` to another Observable which returns nothing: `obs => rxjs.Observable.interval(obs.a*1000)`.
**After this stream is completed**, I next want to pass the second value `b` to other Observable which returns a single value: `obs => rxjs.Observable.of(obs.b*2)`.
Finally I would like to get the last value: b*2=4.
(In my real app, all Observables are HttpRequest objects.)

I first thought of doing this by converting all Observables to Promises and use `await`. But I was wondering if I can do it within RxJS.
Is there any way to do this only by RxJS operators? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use two `switchMap` combined with a `map` operator. Try the following

```js
this.http.get('request1').pipe(   // <-- first request
  switchMap((res) =>              // <-- second request that doesn't return anything
    this.http.post('request2', res.a).pipe(   // <-- use only property `a` from first request
      map(_ => res)               // <-- map back to result from first request
    )
  ),
  switchMap(({ b }) =>            // <-- third request that returns something
    this.http.get('request3')     // <-- use only property `b` from first request
  )
).subscribe({
  next: (result) => {
    console.log(result);          // <-- result from third request
  },
  error: (error) => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, is `b` in the 7th row `res.b`?

Comment: Yes, it's using the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). If you want, you can do similar to prior `switchMap` like `switchMap((res) => this.http.get('request3' + res.b)` or however you wish to use the `b` property.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this. That's good to know. I actually noticed that I need to get a value from the post request (its progress), but it's another issue. Thank you very much for your help!